# find documents by text in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a lots off document with **keyword** in solr

```
<doc>
    <date name="keyword">keyword</date>
</doc>
```

I  have a **text** value that is not saved in solr. This text is not really long (not more than 100 words). I need to find all documents that satisfy this condition:

keyword should be contained in the **text**

How can I write such a query? Or maybe I can save somehow text and then make a request?

Comment: Are your "keyword" and your "text" fields in the same document? Or you have two different types of documents and you are doing alert-style matching?

Comment: what you have tried. ? if you want to query in specific field you can use `/select?textfieldname:keyword`

Comment: Text is not in the document. Text actually even not save in solr

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch you are absolutely right:) it is alert. The original task is: We have a lot of alerts(~1000) with KEYWORD and document that created quite rare. That documents contain TEXT field and if this TEXT contain KEYWORD from alert we should generate some event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java by default is designed as a search engine for user queries, not as an alerting mechanism. There is however [Luwak](https://github.com/flaxsearch/luwak), which is also built on top of Lucene.

Also, Solr is rapidly developing alerting mechanism as part of the stream implementation. It is still in flux and not fully documented, but might be worth watching for. See, for example, [SOLR-8577](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8577) and related issues.

Comment: thank you for this info. I clarify requirements and we will run scheduler every 5 minutes and have not more the 5000 alerts, so I think this count of query should not a problem for solr. I will my be take a look at the Luwak in the future or even better  solr will be have percolate functionality by that time:)